# How to replace the input with url

Tags: python

Hello there I want to code a python program, that opens a website. When you just type a shortcut e.g. "google" it will open "https://www.google.de/". The problem is  that it won´t open the right url.

```
import webbrowser

# URL list

google = "https://www.google.de"
ebay = "https://www.ebay.de/"

# shortcuts

Websites = ("google", "ebay")

def inputString():
    inputstr = input()

    if inputString(google) = ("https://www.google.de")
    else:
        print("Please look for the right shortcut.")

    return

    url = inputString()
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: You could just do `sites = {'google' : 'https://google.de'}` and do `if inputstr in sites: webbrowser.open(sites[inputstr])`. But the code you have now, is not valid python-syntax. but dictionaries will be your friend here. Create as many aliases as you want in your dictionary.

Comment: That's probably because of your method being called with an argument "google" when it doesn't have arguments in the definition. See below the full example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your example you can do:

```
google = "https://www.google.de"
ebay = "https://www.ebay.de/"

def inputString():
    return input()

if inputString() == "google":
    url = google

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Or you can do it the simple way as @torxed said:

```
inputstr = input()
sites = {'google' : 'https://google.de', 'ebay':'https://www.ebay.de/'} 
if inputstr in sites: 
    webbrowser.open(sites[inputstr])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
import webbrowser
import sys

websites = {
    "google":"https://www.google.com",
    "ebay": "https://www.ebay.com"
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        webbrowser.open(websites[sys.argv[1]])
    except:
        print("Please look for the right shortcut:")
        for website in websites:
            print(website)
```

run like so `python browse.py google`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/flozge/Documents/Python Files/Webbrowser!.py", line 18, in <module>
    browse(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range